# icalendar appointment is created, but the reminder is set to "None"

Tags: icalendar

I am creating an `.ics` file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:
SUMMARY:IEP DUE ALERT
ORGANIZER:
LOCATION:
DTSTART:20090429T060000Z
DTEND:20090429T070000Z
DTSTAMP:20090429T185030
DESCRIPTION:An IEP is due for Test, Tyler on 4/29/2009.
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:P0DT1H0M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I am able to create an appointment but the reminder is still set to "None".

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind, 
I was using `Response.ContentType = "text/x-vcalendar"` which is for `vCalendar`
 instead of   `Response.ContentType = "text/calendar"` which is for `iCalendar`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can update the P0DT1H0M to -P0DT1H0M , it work on google calendar